# How to resolve duplicate applications issue when running Django server

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I created a Django app called `session_booker` and added an app called `sessions`. When I try to run my Django server I get this error:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/SessionBooker-fBhCDalc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/SessionBooker-fBhCDalc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/SessionBooker-fBhCDalc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/me/.local/share/virtualenvs/SessionBooker-fBhCDalc/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 93, in populate
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: sessions
```

I'm not even sure where to begin with this one. I guess I've unknowingly created two `sessions` apps. If that's the case is there somewhere I could just delete one? Can anybody tell me how I might fix this?

This is my installed app:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'sessions.apps.SessionsConfig',
]
```

Comment: Please add your installed app from your settings.py

Comment: Now added to the question.

Comment: added an answer; try this and tell me if that worked for you or not

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name sessions interfere with he built in

```
    'django.contrib.sessions',
```

so in your case change the name of the app to something else